# Leveraging a hosted web font service from a local development server?

Tags: fonts, web-services

There are a number of popular web font services on the market today who "host" the fonts and serve them to your web page via javascript or CSS pointing to remote locations. For example http://webfonts.fonts.com or http://typekit.com

However, there seems to be an issue when you're developing on a local testing server - the remote font services don't validate the font and return 403 access denied errors and the like.

What workarounds are there for using remote services such as a hosted font service, on a local development server?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't validate the font?"

Comment: When you get an API key (at least with Monotype) you register certain fonts against a project. Then you get some JS code that loads in the fonts dynamically. The "validation" comment has to do with the assumption that when you try to call in a font using the JavaScript, the server attempts to validate that call against the IP you've registered for that project.

Answer (score 1):

[TypeKit supports use on your own system](http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6857-using-typekit-while-developing-locally) just fine, but you have to explicitly set localhost or 127.0.0.1 in the allowed domains list; nothing is included by default.
I haven't used the fonts.com service, but imagine they have a similar requirement.